# Add extra class for <li>

Tags: php, regex, list

```
$string = '<ul>
   <li id="34334" class="some_class"><a href="/stack/">Text</a></li>
   <li id="someid" class="more_class"><a href="/overflow/">Text</a></li>
</ul>';
```

**What I need** (actually don't know how to do, please help):

1. **We must check `<a>` inside each `<li>`**
2. **If `href` of `<a>` == `/stack/`, then add extra class `current` for parent `<li>`**

---

Like, if we are searching for `/stack/`, we should get this:

```
$string = '<ul>
   <li id="34334" class="some_class current"><a href="/stack/">Text</a></li>
   <li id="someid" class="more_class"><a href="/overflow/">Text</a></li>
   <li id="34334" class="some_class current"><a href="/stack/">Text</a></li>
</ul>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string = '<ul>
   <li class="some_class"><a href="/stack/">Text</a></li>
   <li class="more_class"><a href="/overflow/">Text</a></li>
</ul>';

$new_string = preg_replace('/(<li( +id="[^"]*")? +class=")([^"]*)(" *>)( *<a +href="\/stack\/">)/', '$1$3 current$4$5', $string);
```

**Note:** Updated

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('li > a[href*="stack"]').parent().addClass('newclass');});
```